# Сортировка по двум полям

Tags: mysql

Есть запрос

```
SELECT 
  shop_items.id 
FROM 
  shop_items LEFT JOIN shop_items_price ON shop_items.id=shop_items_price.id_item where shop_items.division = ''
ORDER BY 
  price
```

База `shop_items_price`:

```
id id_item price  saleprice

1  1       150    0

2  2       100    49

3  3       130    99

3  3       50     0
```

Два вопроса:

1. Как сделать сортировку результата по двум полям `price` и `saleprice` одновременно то есть должно быть 49 - 50 - 99 - 150?
2. Как сделать сортировку по размеру скидки - по проценту разницы между `saleprice` и `price` если `saleprice != 0`?

Comment: То есть вы хотите отсортировать не по двум полям, а по меньшему из `price` и `saleprice`, если `saleprice` ненулевой?

Comment: Да! и saleprice  всегда меньше price

Answer (score 3):

> Как сделать сортировку результата по двум полям price и saleprice одновременно то есть должно быть 49 - 50 - 99 - 150?

Используйте такой `order by`, выбираем скидку, если она ненулевая, иначе цену:

```
order by
case when saleprice=0 then price else saleprice end asc
```

---

> Как сделать сортировку по размеру скидки - по проценту разницы между saleprice и price если saleprice != 0?

Аналогично посчитаем отношение скидки к цене  и отсортируем по ней (для товаров без скидки примем за ноль):

```
order by
case when saleprice=0 then 0 else (price-saleprice)/price end asc
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @Глеб44 Не забудьте принять ответ как правильный, если он вам помог (галка слева от ответа)